# popToViewController and memory management

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I have three view controllers pushed in navigationcontroller on the third one i used the statement

`[self.navigationController popToViewController:(Main_View*) mainViewObj animated:YES];`

It takes me directly to my specified controller say first. I have done some coding to remove objects from an NSMutableDictionary in `viewWillDisappear` method in all view controllers, i tried debugging using break points but it never comes to `viewWillDisappear`, it takes me directly to **Main_View**. Should i be worried about removing objects from dictionary or releasing it?

Comment: write in - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: I tried but only viewDidDisappear of the last view controller is being called.

Comment: Dude when popping the view automatically your NSMutableDictionary will be released.

Comment: Yes it will be, soo what about my other tasks like removing objects from it or for example i want to perform some other tasks too in that case? should i be avoiding poptoviewcontroller and use sequence popviewcontroller instead?

Comment: What is your requirement ?

Comment: Actually i am using arc so i don't need to worry abt memory management but when a view disappears i need to do some tasks like removing objects from NSMutableDictionary. For future reference when i need to do more then removing objects can i use poptoviewcontroller?

Comment: When you push new `UIViewController`, previous `UIViewController`'s `viewWillDissappear` is called. so when you do `popToViewContorller`. it'll not be called, since the view ins't appeared again.

Comment: Yes exactly, So Adil what will be the best approach to do some tasks to other viewcontrollers in that case?

Comment: Are you using ARC? or non-ARC?

Comment: i am trying to do for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `viewWillDisappear:` method is not called for the other view controllers because they have already disappeared when you were pushing view controllers on top of them. So basically, `viewWillDisappear:` was already called for them at an earlier point. It wouldn't make sense to call it again, because they weren't visible in the first place.

Comment: Yeah but i made a check (if statement) which only get called when you do popviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller doesn't let it do my tasks, soo if not viewwilldisappear method, then what is most suitable way for that purpose?

Comment: Depends on what you're actually trying to do... It's not really clear from your question *why* you need to remove some objects from a dictionary when a view controller is popped. Are you reusing these view controllers later? If not, you might want to do "cleanup" tasks in `dealloc` instead. Otherwise, you might want to consider subclassing `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to keep weak references to your NSMutableDictanories in your AppDelegate, then after poptoviewcontroller in mainViewController get them, and see, if they are nil, or not, and if not, you can remove objects from Dictionaries in your main view with that references.